# Как передать в imap кириллицу через Python?

Tags: python, кодировка, imap

```
import email

import imaplib

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
mail.login('login@gmail.com', 'pass')
mail.select("inbox")
num = "Кириллица"
data = mail.search(None, "(ON {0})".format(num))
```

Последняя строчка кода должна искать письма по тексту в переменной, но вместо этого она возвращает

```
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 4-11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Устанавливая кодировку 'CHARSET UTF-8' вместо None получаю:

```
SEARCH command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command']
```

Пробовал всё, что знал: кодировка текста во время передачи, декодирование, но результата нет. Если искать английским текстом, то всё работает. Скажите, как в этой ситуации реализовать поиск кириллицей?
То, что пробовал и не сработало:

```
data = mail.search('CHARSET utf-8', "(ON {0})".format(num) )
```

Этот код:

```
data = mail.search('CHARSET UTF8', "(ON {0})".format(num.encode('utf-8'))
```

возвращает следующее:

> Out[106]: ('NO', [b'[BADCHARSET]'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mail.search('utf-8', "(ON {0})".format(num).encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: пробовал ваш вариант. В ответ получаю:"imaplib.IMAP4.error: SEARCH command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command']"

Comment: Гугл привёл меня [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5970286/1911548), где написано, что GMail _support utf-8 strings only when sent as literals_.

Comment: Это помогло! Решение: 
term = u"réception".encode("utf-8")
M.literal = term
M.search("utf-8", "SUBJECT")
Я потратил на это так много часов, но теперь я счастлив! :)